# Fermi--Dirac in pgfplots, dimension too lage

Tags: pgfplots, dimensions

I'm trying to draw a plot of the Fermi-Dirac distribution,

[image]

for which I'd like to show a few lines of varied temperate (T). My code works for this, except for zero temperature, it results in a `Dimension too large` error from pgfplots. Is there a way to resolve this while keeping the real value of the Boltzman constant, `k_B`, in electron volts?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$\frac{mv^2}{2k_BT}$ (eV),
    ylabel=$f(n)$,
    legend entries={0 K,100 K,1000 K,10000 K},
    x tick style={color=black},
    y tick style={color=black},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=1.1
    ]
\addplot[samples=50,black] {(1/((exp((x)/(80.617e-5))+1))};
\addplot[samples=50,blue,dashed] {(1/((exp((x)/(8.617e-3))+1))};
\addplot[samples=50,red,dashed] {(1/((exp((x)/(8.617e-2))+1))};
\addplot[samples=50,green,dashed] {(1/((exp((x)/(8.617e-1))+1))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code compiles but `80.617e-5` should be `8.617e-5` which breaks the code. I've tried varying/removing `xmin`, `xmax` with no success. I also read in a few answers something to do with `fpu` but this didn't seem to work for me or is no longer required?  `restrict x to domain` did not seem to help, though I could be using it wrong.

[image]

Comment: TeX does not really support floating point numbers.  Tikz fakes it using dimen registers (fixed point) and converting everything into text.  To do it right you should compute the numbers elsewhere and import them using plgplotstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause is a deficiency in the TeX based floating point unit employed by `pgfplots`. An intermediate result requires to compute

```
\begingroup
%\tracingmacros=2 \tracingcommands=2
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfmathparse{exp(-3.4814e4)}\pgfmathresult
\endgroup
```

which reaches some internal limit. I accept that as bug report and will see if I can fix it.

For the time being, you can consider to compile your example with

- `pgfplots` in version 1.12 or newer and
- `lualatex` .

This will work out of the box (as soon as you fix the syntax error in your first `\addplot` expression, there is a round brace too much in it).

Comment: I must have added a set of parentheses when trying to get it to work. It works, as you said, with LuaLaTeX, pgfplots v1.12 and `\addplot[samples=250,black] {1/(exp((x)/(8.617e-5))+1)};` I'll have to read up on how Lua handles the situation for my knowledge.

Comment: Ok, great. If I am not mistaken, there is a hidden question like "why does lua help here" behind your comment. If so, the answer would be: `pgfplots` comes with a partial reimplementation in lua and switches to lua whenever it can. See `lua backend` in the `pgfplots` reference manual for details http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/